# UWP app how to make background completely black

Tags: c#, xaml, search, web, uwp

I set page background black and when doing nothing there is no problem, but when I click a `TextBox` when keyboard opens or when I change phone layout like horizontal to vertical I see white color in edges how can I make them black too?

Comment: can you show a screenshot of what do you mean white edges?

Answer (score 1):

Are you changing the page or the grid background. I would assume you are only changing the grid background not the page.

The below example is changing both the page and the grid.

```
<Page
    Background="Black"
    x:Class="Rasberry_Pi_Trebuchet.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Rasberry_Pi_Trebuchet"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="Black">

    </Grid>
</Page>
```